# Unsupported currency errors while deploying Reports from one org to another

Tags: reporting, deployment

I am trying to deploy reports, report types and dashboards from one org to other using Eclipse Force.com IDE.

I am getting following error:

> currency: Unsupported currency: EUR.

My first thought was that this may be due to multi-currency enabled in either of the orgs. However, multi-currency is not enabled in any of the org.

The default currency locale in Company Information is same in both the orgs which is USD.

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Hi I am also facing the same issue when trying to deploy report using SFDX CLI. Invalid Currency. Can you tell me how you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when deploying reports without multi-currency being enabled. I was able to resolve this error by re-saving the report in the target org and then re-attempting the deployment.